# How to store category in database (iOS 9 Swift, Core Data)

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data, enums

I'm building a simple note app and I currently have a note entity in the database.

Now I want to add a note category in the database and I'm wondering what will be the most appropriate way to create this. It needs to hold a few static records to start with and user should be able to add more later if needed.

I was thinking to store the static default values in `enum` and make the note category an attribute of the note entity as an integer.

```
enum NoteCategory: Int32 {
    case General, Grocery ....
}
```

But then, `enum` is not designed to scale dynamically so it may be not a feasible option for me.

Alternatively, I thought of creating the note category as an entity and make relationship with the note entity with category id associated but in this case I'm not sure how I can store static records to begin with.

What would be the best option that would fit my needs?

Comment: Use the second approach. The first time your app runs insert the static categories into core data

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you, I'll go with the 2nd approach. I'm happy to close this thread if you make this as an answer.